# If statements inside for loop of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, if-statement

I'm currently trying to create a responsive slider where the user can choose how many items display on screen, he can decide how many item on every custom mediaquery he wants.
So my idea is to pass a obj with all the mediaqueries

```
$(".slider-container1").slider({
        itemsOnScreen:          5,
        spaceBetween:           20,
        draggable:              true,
        responsive:             {
            "480":      2, // from 0 to 480 display 2 items
            "768":      3, // from 481 to 768 display 3 items
            "1024":     4  // from 769 to 1024 display 4 items
            // the behaviour of the slider NOT ranged here come from the previous property "itemsOnScreen"
        }
});
```

Then I store it inside a slider property `mq` so I can access it in a easy way

```
var slider = {
    mq: params.responsive
};
```

Then comes the hard part.
My idea was to create a function inside

```
$(document).on('resize', function(){
    beResponsive();
});
```

where the function beResponsive() control the resposive part of the slider. 
My idea was to create a loop based on the `slider.mq` in this way

```
function beResponsive() {
        for(var width in slider.mq){
            if ("width is between two values stored in slider.mq") {"do stuff to do responsive"};
        }
    }
beResponsive();
```

In this way i cannot get it work because I can't find a way to access to two different properties of the obj at the same time (for example 480 and 768).
Any idea to achieve this? Any other idea about performances? Any others better way to achieve that?

### EDIT

I did it in this way and looks like it works, but I'm not sure it's the correct way to do that because maybe it's not performance good, because as you know this func will be fired every resize

```
function beResponsive() {
        var lowerWidth = 0;
        var inMediaQuery = false;
        for(var mqWidth in slider.mq){
            if (helpers.vw() > lowerWidth && (helpers.vw() <= parseInt(mqWidth))) {
                inMediaQuery = true;
                console.log("I'm between " + lowerWidth + "  and " + mqWidth);
                break;
            }
            lowerWidth = mqWidth;                   
        }
        if (!inMediaQuery) {
            console.log("bigger than anyone");
        }
    }
beResponsive();
```

### EDIT2

Actually I improved it with a control `WHEN` it changes mediaquery, this will prevent to fire a function when the user resize and it's still in the same mediaquery

```
function beResponsive() {
        var lowerWidth = 0;
        var inMediaQuery = false;
        for(var mqWidth in slider.mq){
            if (helpers.vw() > lowerWidth && (helpers.vw() <= parseInt(mqWidth))) {
                if (helpers.currentMq != parseInt(mqWidth)) {
                    // doStuff 
                    helpers.currentMq = mqWidth;

                }
                inMediaQuery = true;
                break;
            }
            lowerWidth = mqWidth;                   
        }
        if (!inMediaQuery) { // i'm not in a declared mediaquery, so go back to default 
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    beResponsive();
```

[image: What i mean as "items on screen"]

Comment: As of today most frameworks just fixiate the break points in their code - see bootstrap or foundation. Why don't you just set 3 breakpoints (maybe as an option as well) and just go down the road with 3 if statements?

Comment: @AlexanderKludt for 2 reasons: I know a lot of websites that have a lot of mediaqueries so I'd like to fit my slider into every needs, and second I'm challenging myself, this helps me learn js better and create something maybe useful for someone :)

Comment: Are you going to rely that `responsive` object holds these three values - `480, 768, 1024` or you want to pass there different values and they could possibly be different number not always 3?

Comment: I would let the user choose everything.
Btw, I updated the asnwer.

Comment: I thinl there should be always some assumption, because you should have three or four functions to handle the design for example `responsiveSmall(); responsiveMiddle(), responsiveLarge()` and you should know in what scenario you should call this functions. Am I correct? What information is the values in `responsive` object bringing to you actually ? I mean `"480": 2` the 2, 3 and 5 in your code ?

Comment: I don't need 3 different functions because I only change the number of items visible. The behaviour is always the same @sand

Comment: @dghez have a look on this sample https://jsfiddle.net/xwu5wcae/1/ and let me know if this is making sense to you  (watch your console to see expected results and resize browser)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xwu5wcae/2/ check here because I saw the other was not quite correct

Comment: Unless you are doing something other than just calling `beResponsive` in the `resize` event handler, you don't need to wrap it in an anonymous function like that, you can just use `beResponsive` as the handler: `$(document).on('resize', beResponsive);`.

Comment: @sand that's esentially what I did in my update, but you added the case when the mediaqueries aren't in order. Thanks for that, I didn't think about that ;)

Comment: @dghez you are welcome, I hope you will make an amazing slider plugin :) Good luck!

Comment: actually I improved it by using a control to detect if I'm still in the same mediaquery on resize, so I will not call the function that "do stuff" on every resize@sand